# Struggling getting coverage on 4 lines of code - Trigger

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

I Have written my test class and it now works fine with all my code but I can't get coverage on on these 4 lines. The else statement is fine but the assignment inside the if statement is not covered. I have tried assigning owner Id's to the test case making sure to abide to all the conditions but it still wont work.

Any ideas?

Edit: its to do with case assignment so

cc = Case

Case_Assignee_Work_Request_iGrasp is a field which we pull a userId from

Class is below:

```
for (Case cc : [Select OwnerId, Id, AccountId, RecordType.Name, product__c,  AssetId From Case  where  id in :Trigger.new]){ 
      System.debug(Logginglevel.INFO, 'CaseOwnerAssignee | Account found - id  1 : ' + cc.AccountId);

      if (cc.AccountId == null ) {
            for (Asset asset : [Select AccountId from Asset where Id = : cc.AssetId]){
               System.debug(Logginglevel.INFO, 'CaseOwnerAssignee | Account found - id  2 : ' + asset.AccountId);

                AccountId = asset.AccountId;
                cc.AccountId = AccountId;
                AccountFound = true; 
                AccountLookupRequired = true;
            }
      }
      else{ 
           System.debug(Logginglevel.INFO, 'CaseOwnerAssignee | Account found - id  3 : ' + cc.AccountId);
           AccountId = cc.AccountId;
           AccountFound = true; 
      }
      // Get Case Assignee owners from Account
      for (Account Acc : [Select IG_TLK_Owner__c, Case_Assignee_Work_Request_iGrasp__c, Case_Assignee_Work_Request_ETWeb__c, Case_Assignee_Incident_iGrasp__c, Case_Assignee_Incident_ETWeb__c, OwnerId
          From Account  where  id  = : AccountId]){
          Case_Assignee_Work_Request_TalentLink = Acc.IG_TLK_Owner__c;
          Case_Assignee_Work_Request_iGrasp = Acc.Case_Assignee_Work_Request_iGrasp__c;
          Case_Assignee_Work_Request_ETWeb = Acc.Case_Assignee_Work_Request_ETWeb__c;
          Case_Assignee_Incident_iGrasp = Acc.Case_Assignee_Incident_iGrasp__c;
          Case_Assignee_Incident_ETWeb = Acc.Case_Assignee_Incident_ETWeb__c;

if (ProductName == 'i-GRasp'){
if (Case_Assignee_Work_Request_iGrasp != null){
                       cc.OwnerId =   Case_Assignee_Work_Request_IGrasp ; // << NO COVERAGE
                       cc.Case_Owner_Assignee_Trigger_used__c = true; //<< NO COVERAGE
                       cc.AccountId =  AccountId;  //<< NO COVERAGE
                       caseList.Add(cc); // << NO COVERAGE
                   }
                   else{
                        System.debug(Logginglevel.INFO, 'CaseOwnerAssignee | Work Request - IGrasp 2 ' );
                        cc.OwnerId = AccountOwnerId; 
                        cc.Case_Owner_Assignee_Trigger_used__c = true;
                        cc.AccountId =  AccountId;  
                        caseList.Add(cc);
```

**Test Class**

```
    @isTest
public class TestCaseAssignee {

  static testmethod void TestCaseAssignee1() {

    //****** @modified by Anna, 19 Oct 2016 to fixed error due to Validation Rule "'Billing Country' contains an invalid country name" *****/
    /*
    pw_cc__CountryObject__c country = new pw_cc__CountryObject__c(
      Name = 'United States',
      pw_cc__IsoCode_2__c = 'US',
      pw_cc__IsoCode_3__c = 'USA'
    );
    insert country;
    */
    //****************************************************************** END *************************************************************//

    User TestUser = null;
    Id TestCaseId = null;
    Id TestUserId = null;
    Id TestAssetIGRaspId = null;
    Id TestAssetETWebId = null;
    Id TestAssetTalentLinkId = null;
    Id RecordTypeIncidentId = null;
    Id RecordTypeWorkRequestId = null;
    Id ProductIGRaspId = null;
    Id ProductETWebId = null;
    Id ProductTalentLinkId = null;
    Id Case_Assignee_Work_Request_iGrasp = null;
    Id Case_Assignee_Work_Request_ETWeb = null;
    Id Case_Assignee_Incident_iGrasp = null;
    Id Case_Assignee_Incident_ETWeb = null;
    Id Case_Assignee_Work_Request_TalentLink = null;

    Profile p1 = [select id from profile where name = 'System Administrator'];

    User u = new User(alias = 'standt', email = 'standarduser@testorg.com',
                      emailencodingkey = 'UTF-8', lastname = 'Testing', languagelocalekey = 'en_US',
                      localesidkey = 'en_US', profileid = p1.Id,
                      timezonesidkey = 'America/Los_Angeles', username = 'standarduser@testorg.com');
    User u1 = new User(alias = 'standt', email = 'standarduser1@testorg.com',
                       emailencodingkey = 'UTF-8', lastname = 'Testing1', languagelocalekey = 'en_US',
                       localesidkey = 'en_US', profileid = p1.Id,
                       timezonesidkey = 'America/Los_Angeles', username = 'standarduser1@testorg.com');
    User u2 = new User(alias = 'standt', email = 'standarduser2@testorg.com',
                       emailencodingkey = 'UTF-8', lastname = 'Testing2', languagelocalekey = 'en_US',
                       localesidkey = 'en_US', profileid = p1.Id,
                       timezonesidkey = 'America/Los_Angeles', username = 'standarduser2@testorg.com');
    User u3 = new User(alias = 'standt', email = 'standarduser3@testorg.com',
                       emailencodingkey = 'UTF-8', lastname = 'Testing3', languagelocalekey = 'en_US',
                       localesidkey = 'en_US', profileid = p1.Id,
                       timezonesidkey = 'America/Los_Angeles', username = 'standarduser3@testorg.com');
    User u4 = new User(alias = 'standt', email = 'standarduser4@testorg.com',
                       emailencodingkey = 'UTF-8', lastname = 'Testing4', languagelocalekey = 'en_US',
                       localesidkey = 'en_US', profileid = p1.Id,
                       timezonesidkey = 'America/Los_Angeles', username = 'standarduser4@testorg.com');

    User u5 = new User(alias = 'standt', email = 'standarduser5@testorg.com',
                       emailencodingkey = 'UTF-8', lastname = 'Testing5', languagelocalekey = 'en_US',
                       localesidkey = 'en_US', profileid = p1.Id,
                       timezonesidkey = 'America/Los_Angeles', username = 'standarduser5@testorg.com', isActive=false);

    TestUser = u;
    TestUserId = u.Id;

    RecordTypeIncidentId = [Select Id From RecordType  where sObjectType = 'Case' and Name = 'Incident'].id;
    RecordTypeWorkRequestId = [Select Id From RecordType  where sObjectType = 'Case' and Name = 'Work Request'].id;

    for (Product2 p : [Select p.Name, p.Id From Product2 p where p.Name = 'i-GRasp' Limit 1]) {
      ProductIGRaspId = p.Id;
      System.debug('### ProductIGRaspId ' + ProductIGRaspId + '  ###' );
    }

    for (Product2 p : [Select p.Name, p.Id From Product2 p where p.Name Like 'ETWeb%' Limit 1]) { //@modified by Anna, 20 Oct: Change from  [= 'ETWeb'] => [Like 'ETWeb%']
    //for (Product2 p : [Select p.Name, p.Id From Product2 p where p.Name = 'ETWeb' Limit 1]) {
      ProductETWebId = p.Id;
      System.debug('### ProductETWebId ' + ProductETWebId + '  ###' );
    }

    Account TestAccount = new Account (name = 'Test Account', BillingStreet = '1 Main St.', BillingState = 'VA', BillingPostalCode = '12345', BillingCountry = 'United States', BillingCity = 'Anytown');
    TestAccount.Case_Assignee_Incident_ETWeb__c = u1.id;
    TestAccount.Case_Assignee_Incident_iGrasp__c = u2.id;
    TestAccount.Case_Assignee_Work_Request_ETWeb__c = u3.Id;
    TestAccount.Case_Assignee_Work_Request_iGRasp__c = u4.Id;
    Case_Assignee_Work_Request_iGRasp = u4.Id;
    TestAccount.IG_TLK_Owner__c = u5.Id;
    TestAccount.Type = 'Other';
    insert TestAccount;
    system.debug('Account Test Account has been added' + TestAccount.Id);

    Asset TestAssetIGRasp = new Asset();
    TestAssetIGRasp.Name = 'Test Component IGrasp';
    TestAssetIGRasp.AccountId = TestAccount.Id;
    TestAssetIGRasp.Product2Id = ProductIGRaspId;
    insert TestAssetIGRasp;
    TestAssetIGRaspId = TestAssetIGRasp.Id;
    system.debug('Test Component has been added ' + TestAssetIGRasp.Id );

    Asset TestAssetETWeb = new Asset();
    TestAssetETWeb.Name = 'Test Component ETWeb';
    TestAssetETWeb.AccountId = TestAccount.Id;
    TestAssetETWeb.Product2Id = ProductETWebId;
    insert TestAssetETWeb;
    TestAssetETWebId = TestAssetETWeb.Id;
    system.debug('Test Component has been added ' + TestAssetETWEb.Id );

    Asset TestAssetTalentLink = new Asset();
    TestAssetTalentLink.Name = 'Test Component TalentLink';
    TestAssetTalentLink.AccountId = TestAccount.Id;
    TestAssetTalentLink.Product2Id = ProductTalentLinkId;
   // insert TestAssetTalentLink;
    //TestAssetTalentLinkId = TestAssetTalentLink.Id;
    system.debug('Test Component has been added ' + TestAssetTalentLink.Id );

    system.debug('Add Incident i-GRasp case');
    Case TestCase1 = new Case();
    TestCase1.accountid = TestAccount.id;
    TestCase1.subject = 'Test Case';
    TestCase1.recordtypeid = RecordTypeIncidentId;
    TestCase1.Origin = 'Phone';
    TestCase1.WR_Case_Actions__c = 'New';
    TestCase1.Description = 'Desc 123';
    TestCase1.Status = 'New';
    TestCase1.AssetId = TestAssetIGRaspId;
    insert TestCase1 ;
    system.debug('Test Case 1 has been added ' + TestCase1.Id );

    system.debug('Add Incident ETWeb case');
    Case TestCase2 = new Case();
    TestCase2.accountid = TestAccount.id;
    TestCase2.subject = 'Test Case';
    TestCase2.recordtypeid = RecordTypeIncidentId;
    TestCase2.Origin = 'Phone';
    TestCase2.WR_Case_Actions__c = 'New';
    TestCase2.Description = 'Desc 123';
    TestCase2.Status = 'New';
    TestCase2.AssetId = TestAssetETWebId;
    insert TestCase2 ;
    system.debug('Test Case 2 has been added ' + TestCase2.Id );

  }
  static testmethod void TestCaseAssignee2() {

    //****** @modified by Anna, 19 Oct 2016 to fixed error due to Validation Rule "'Billing Country' contains an invalid country name" *****/
    /*
    pw_cc__CountryObject__c country = new pw_cc__CountryObject__c(
      Name = 'United States',
      pw_cc__IsoCode_2__c = 'US',
      pw_cc__IsoCode_3__c = 'USA'
    );
    insert country;
    */
    //****************************************************************** END *************************************************************//

    User TestUser = null;
    Id TestCaseId = null;
    Id TestUserId = null;
    Id TestAssetIGRaspId = null;
    Id TestAssetETWebId = null;
    Id TestAssetTalentLinkId = null;
    Id RecordTypeIncidentId = null;
    Id RecordTypeWorkRequestId = null;
    Id ProductIGRaspId = null;
    Id ProductETWebId = null;
    Id ProductTalentLinkId = null;
    Id Case_Assignee_Work_Request_iGrasp = null;
    Id Case_Assignee_Work_Request_ETWeb = null;
    Id Case_Assignee_Incident_iGrasp = null;
    Id Case_Assignee_Incident_ETWeb = null;

    Profile p1 = [select id from profile where name = 'System Administrator'];

    User u = new User(alias = 'standt', email = 'standarduser@testorg.com',
                      emailencodingkey = 'UTF-8', lastname = 'Testing', languagelocalekey = 'en_US',
                      localesidkey = 'en_US', profileid = p1.Id,
                      timezonesidkey = 'America/Los_Angeles', username = 'standarduser@testorg.com');
    User u1 = new User(alias = 'standt', email = 'standarduser1@testorg.com',
                       emailencodingkey = 'UTF-8', lastname = 'Testing1', languagelocalekey = 'en_US',
                       localesidkey = 'en_US', profileid = p1.Id,
                       timezonesidkey = 'America/Los_Angeles', username = 'standarduser1@testorg.com');
    User u2 = new User(alias = 'standt', email = 'standarduser2@testorg.com',
                       emailencodingkey = 'UTF-8', lastname = 'Testing2', languagelocalekey = 'en_US',
                       localesidkey = 'en_US', profileid = p1.Id,
                       timezonesidkey = 'America/Los_Angeles', username = 'standarduser2@testorg.com');
    User u3 = new User(alias = 'standt', email = 'standarduser3@testorg.com',
                       emailencodingkey = 'UTF-8', lastname = 'Testing3', languagelocalekey = 'en_US',
                       localesidkey = 'en_US', profileid = p1.Id,
                       timezonesidkey = 'America/Los_Angeles', username = 'standarduser3@testorg.com');
    User u4 = new User(alias = 'standt', email = 'standarduser4@testorg.com',
                       emailencodingkey = 'UTF-8', lastname = 'Testing4', languagelocalekey = 'en_US',
                       localesidkey = 'en_US', profileid = p1.Id,
                       timezonesidkey = 'America/Los_Angeles', username = 'standarduser4@testorg.com');
    User u5 = new User(alias = 'standt', email = 'standarduser5@testorg.com',
                       emailencodingkey = 'UTF-8', lastname = 'Testing5', languagelocalekey = 'en_US',
                       localesidkey = 'en_US', profileid = p1.Id,
                       timezonesidkey = 'America/Los_Angeles', username = 'standarduser5@testorg.com');

    TestUser = u;
    TestUserId = u.Id;

    RecordTypeIncidentId = [Select Id From RecordType  where sObjectType = 'Case' and Name = 'Incident'].id;
    RecordTypeWorkRequestId = [Select Id From RecordType  where sObjectType = 'Case' and Name = 'Work Request'].id;

    for (Product2 p : [Select p.Name, p.Id From Product2 p where p.Name = 'i-GRasp' Limit 1]) {
      ProductIGRaspId = p.Id;
      System.debug('### ProductIGRaspId ' + ProductIGRaspId + '  ###' );
    }
    for (Product2 p : [Select p.Name, p.Id From Product2 p where p.Name Like 'ETWeb%' Limit 1]) { //@modified by Anna, 20 Oct: Change from  [= 'ETWeb'] => [Like 'ETWeb%']
    //for (Product2 p : [Select p.Name, p.Id From Product2 p where p.Name = 'ETWeb' Limit 1]) {
      ProductETWebId = p.Id;
      System.debug('### ProductETWebId ' + ProductETWebId + '  ###' );
    }
    for (Product2 p : [Select p.Name, p.Id From Product2 p where p.Name = 'TalentLink' Limit 1]) { //@modified by Anna, 20 Oct: Change from  [= 'ETWeb'] => [Like 'ETWeb%']
    //for (Product2 p : [Select p.Name, p.Id From Product2 p where p.Name = 'ETWeb' Limit 1]) {
      ProductTalentLinkId = p.Id;
      System.debug('### ProductETWebId ' + ProductETWebId + '  ###' );
    }

    Account TestAccount = new Account (name = 'Test Account', BillingStreet = '1 Main St.', BillingState = 'VA', BillingPostalCode = '12345', BillingCountry = 'United States', BillingCity = 'Anytown');
    TestAccount.Case_Assignee_Incident_ETWeb__c = u1.id;
    TestAccount.Case_Assignee_Incident_iGrasp__c = u2.id;
    TestAccount.Case_Assignee_Work_Request_ETWeb__c = u3.Id;
    TestAccount.Case_Assignee_Work_Request_iGRasp__c = u4.Id;
    Case_Assignee_Work_Request_iGrasp = u4.Id;
    TestAccount.Type = 'Other';
    insert TestAccount;
    system.debug('Account Test Account has been added' + TestAccount.Id);
    system.debug('Account Test Account has been added' + TestAccount.Case_Assignee_Incident_ETWeb__c);
    Asset TestAssetIGRasp = new Asset();
    TestAssetIGRasp.Name = 'Test Component IGrasp';
    TestAssetIGRasp.AccountId = TestAccount.Id;
    TestAssetIGRasp.Product2Id = ProductIGRaspId;
    insert TestAssetIGRasp;
    TestAssetIGRaspId = TestAssetIGRasp.Id;
    system.debug('Test Component has been added ' + TestAssetIGRasp.Id );

    Asset TestAssetETWeb = new Asset();
    TestAssetETWeb.Name = 'Test Component ETWeb';
    TestAssetETWeb.AccountId = TestAccount.Id;
    TestAssetETWeb.Product2Id = ProductETWebId;
    insert TestAssetETWeb;
    TestAssetETWebId = TestAssetETWeb.Id;
    system.debug('Test Component has been added ' + TestAssetETWEb.Id );

    system.debug('Add Work Request ETWeb case');
    //System.assert(Case_Assignee_Incident_IGrasp != null);
    //System.assert(Case_Assignee_Incident_ETWEb != null);
    User u6 = new User(alias = 'standt', email = 'standarduser6@testorg.com',
                       emailencodingkey = 'UTF-8', lastname = 'Testing6', languagelocalekey = 'en_US',
                       localesidkey = 'en_US', profileid = p1.Id,
                       timezonesidkey = 'America/Los_Angeles', username = 'standarduser6@testorg.com');
    System.debug('UserID = ' + u6.id);
    insert u6;
    List<Case> cc = new List<Case>();
    Case TestCase4 = 
        new Case();
    TestCase4.accountid = TestAccount.id;
    TestCase4.subject = 'Test Case';
    TestCase4.recordtypeid = RecordTypeWorkRequestId;
    TestCase4.Origin = 'Phone';
    TestCase4.WR_Case_Actions__c = 'New';
    TestCase4.Description = 'Desc 123';
    TestCase4.Status = 'New';
    TestCase4.AssetId = TestAssetETWebId;
    TestCase4.Reason_WR_Not_Linked_to_Opportunity__c = 'This is a test';
    insert TestCase4 ;
    system.debug('Test Case 4 has been added ' + TestCase4.Id );


    system.debug('Add Work Request i-GRasp case');
    Case TestCase5 = new Case();
    TestCase5.subject = 'Test Case';
    TestCase5.recordtypeid = RecordTypeWorkRequestId;
    TestCase5.Origin = 'Phone';
    TestCase5.WR_Case_Actions__c = 'New';
    TestCase5.Description = 'Desc 123';
    TestCase5.Status = 'New';
    TestCase5.AssetId = TestAssetIGRaspId;
    TestCase5.Reason_WR_Not_Linked_to_Opportunity__c = 'This is a test';
    insert TestCase5 ;
    system.debug('Test Case 5 has been added ' + TestCase5.Id );


    system.debug('Add Incident ETWeb case');

    Case TestCase6 = new Case();
    TestCase6.subject = 'Test Case';
    TestCase6.ownerId = u6.Id;
    System.debug('OwnerId' + TestCase6.ownerId);
    TestCase6.recordtypeid = RecordTypeIncidentId;
    TestCase6.Origin = 'Phone';
    TestCase6.WR_Case_Actions__c = 'New';
    TestCase6.Description = 'Desc 123';
    TestCase6.Status = 'New';
    TestCase6.AssetId = TestAssetETWebId;
    TestCase6.Reason_WR_Not_Linked_to_Opportunity__c = 'This is a test';
    TestCase6.Case_Owner_Assignee_Trigger_used__c = true;
    insert TestCase6 ;
    system.debug('Test Case 6 has been added ' + TestCase6.Id );

    system.debug('Add Incident iGrasp case');

    Case TestCase7 = new Case();
    TestCase7.subject = 'Test Case';
    TestCase7.recordtypeid = RecordTypeIncidentId;
    TestCase7.Origin = 'Phone';
    TestCase7.WR_Case_Actions__c = 'New';
    TestCase7.Description = 'Desc 123';
    TestCase7.Status = 'New';
    TestCase7.AssetId = TestAssetIGRaspId;
    TestCase7.Reason_WR_Not_Linked_to_Opportunity__c = 'This is a test';
    insert TestCase7 ;
    system.debug('Test Case 7 has been added ' + TestCase7.Id );  

    Case TestCase8 = new Case();
    TestCase8.subject = 'Test Case';
    TestCase8.recordtypeid = RecordTypeWorkRequestId;
    TestCase8.Origin = 'Phone';
    TestCase8.WR_Case_Actions__c = 'New';
    TestCase8.Description = 'Desc 123';
    TestCase8.Status = 'New';
    TestCase8.AssetId = TestAssetIGRaspId;
    TestCase8.Reason_WR_Not_Linked_to_Opportunity__c = 'This is a test';
    insert TestCase8 ;
    system.debug('Test Case 7 has been added ' + TestCase8.Id );
  }

}
```

Comment: Looks like you're never populating `Case_Assignee_Work_Request_iGrasp`...however there's nowhere near enough context included in your post for us to help.

Comment: Please share any test you have already written. You need to set that field on the parent account. You also need to remove that query from your loop!